# Matrix norm $|| g^{-1}||$

Tags: matrices

In first line of the proof to theorem 1.2 of this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00537227.  The author stated

If $g\in SL(m,\mathbb{R})$, and $|| g||=m \max_{i,j} |g_{ij}|$ then $|| g^{-1}||\le || g||^{m-1}$.

How do we show this implication is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: last proof was totally wrong, here is a revised one:

Since $g \in SL(m,\mathbb{R})$, $\det(g) = 1$ and so $g^{-1} = \frac{\text{adj}(g)}{\det(g)} = \text{adj}(g)$ where adj denotes the adjugate matrix. This shows that the norms of the entries of $g^{-1}$ are exactly the norms of the first minors $M_{ij}$ of $g$, and so to bound $||g^{-1}||$ it is enough to bound the latter. We know that $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of a $(m-1)\times(m-1)$ sub-matrix $A$ of $g$, so that the norm of every entry of $A$ is bounded by $\frac{||g||}{m}$. Thus by the Leibniz formula for determinants, $M_{ij}$ is bounded by $(m-1)!\cdot\left(\frac{||g||}{m}\right)^{m-1}$ and so
    $$ ||g^{-1}|| \leq m!\cdot\left(\frac{||g||}{m}\right)^{m-1} = \frac{m!}{m^{m-1}}\cdot||g||^{m-1}. $$
    Noting that $m! \leq m^{m-1}$ for every $m \geq 1$ completes the proof.

Comment: Why is this inequality true$$\frac{1}{|a_0|}(||g^{m-1}|| + \ldots + ||a_1||) \leq \frac{||g^{m-1}||}{|a_0|}$$ when $||g^i||$ are all nonnegative

Comment: Sorry, brain fart. I'll edit a fix in a sec

Comment: This proof should be better, sorry about that